# Customize default user folders

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, user-folders

Can't seem to figure out if this is possible as all the search terms I try give unrelated information.  I was wondering if windows 8 allows for me to change what the default user's folders contains (i.e. I'd like to add a folder).

[image]

Is there a way to add your own folders to these prestigious locations, so I get the nice front space when opening my windows explorer that these have?

Comment: Well, you should be able to drag any file/folder to a space in the sidebar. Try that and see what happens.

Comment: You get a red X

Comment: Hm. I'm upvoting this because I'm curious if there's a way. It's probably possible through the registry or even Folder Settings.

Comment: Custom default folders?? YOU KNOW WE'RE TRYING TO LIVE IN A SOCIETY HERE!!!

Comment: You can only add a network location. But else you can only play with the folders that are already there (add/remove).

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way than to change the registry. Try [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/28025-pc-add-remove-folders-windows-8-1-a.html) tutorial. You could remove things you don't want and just use favorites.

Comment: Works for removing the defaults, but nothing about adding your own.  It seems each one just has a random guid you add to the registry and it automagically adds / removes one of the default folders?

Comment: Looks like a guy at this site was able to write a program that adds custom folders, but he doesn't give his source or tell exactly how he did it: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-folders-in-this-pc-in-windows-8-1-or-remove-the-defaults/

Comment: @KDiTraglia: Should be possible to use Process Monitor to see what that app does.

Comment: @Karan based on comments looks like it is likely packaged with some spyware, so I'd prefer not to run it =P.

Comment: @KDiTraglia: You mean the WinAero app? I doubt that's the case; AV heuristics must be flagging it because it modifies system files. Anyway it's up to you. If no-one figures out what that app does and you're really interested, you can always run both it and Process Monitor inside a VM.

Comment: Could you please [edit your answer](http://superuser.com/posts/907857/edit) to include the relevant information from the link in your post? This will make sure your answer remains useful should the linked site ever change or disappear.